# No data for masters thesis

Tags: thesis

So I’m having my masters in Italy. My thesis is on a project with an Italian organization sponsored by the World Bank in Burundi, East Africa.

I was able to collect the baseline data from my sample. However, there are issues with the local government who has banned any international organizations working in Burundi. I foresee this as a big problem and I may not be able to collect my post intervention data. How do I conclude my thesis? Can I graduate without the complete data for my research?

Comment: This is the kind of advice your advisor is much better positioned to give than people on the internet, since your advisor presumably knows the local rules about theses and graduation, and is more familiar with your research.

Answer (score 5):

Just to let you know that this question may likely be closed due to being too specifically dependent on your institute's policy.

The best people to answer you are: i) Your supervisor and your committee (do they think there are enough "meats" from the baseline data to sustain a Master level analysis? Would there be other projects from which you can carve out an aim for your thesis?) ii) The academic committee overseeing the execution of the curriculum (how do they consider disruption due to unforeseen circumstances? Do they need a revised research plan?) iii) The funding organization (Are they fine with only having the baseline data report?, etc.)

In this kind of position, as a student, it may be easy to fall into panic mode and let the flow take you. But do think deeply and clearly about it, and voice what you'd like to achieve. If you want to get the follow up data collected, then talk to your faculty who connected you with WB and see if you can partner with/contract a local agency to collect the data for you (assuming your intervention was delivered somewhat to the plan). Your team may need to seek legal advice as well, but if you do have the will to get this finished, don't give up the first time just because you're told not to.

If it's not a go, or the intervention is unfortunately cut short or terminated, consider proposing a new aim, perhaps focusing on literature review, on the potential impact on outcomes (the ones you are working on) during political instability or other disruptions, etc. That's another logical next step you can consider.

Comment: +1, especially for the suggestion to try to work with a local organization.